# How to prevent dataset from loosing the dataflow binding after import?

Tags: powerbi

I have 2 workspaces. Uat and prod.

Each workspace has a dataflow, dataset and reports, with the same name used in both workspaces.

After UAT, to promote the dataflow into prod workspace, I first delete the dataflow from prod workspace (as it doesnt support overrite). Then export dataflow from uat workspace and import into prod workspace. This causes datasets in prod workspace to stop working as they seem to be looking for the original dataflow (the newly imported dataflow has a different id).

Then I have to fix each dataset to point to the new dataflow id.

How to prevent dataset from lossing binding with original dataflow after import? Or is there any workaround this problem?

Comment: Deleting and recreating a dataflow seems like a bad way to modify it. This prevents a stable dataflow ID.

Comment: I am looking for a way to import the dataflow and overwrite to keep the original id. And prevent datasets from breaking. But can't find a way

Comment: Edit the dataflow rather than recreating it.

Comment: I dont find it good idea to manually edit to maintain the sync because there are chances of error during the manual work. I wish power bi allowed to overwrite like how it is allowed for datasets.